# backward compatibility of play-1.2.3

Tags: playframework

When upgrading from Play 1.2.1 to 1.2.3, I get some compilation errors. For instance: `WsAsync.newRequest` takes now two parameter instead of one.

Play 1.2.3 has got two play jars: Play.jar and play-1.2.3.jar. Play.jar seems to have the earlier version of `newRequest`, and if both jars are added to the build path in eclipse, there are no compilation errors. But when I run Play it seems to only use play-1.2.3.jar. I even tried to copy play.jar to the application lib directory without solving the problem.

Can somebody tell me how to use the two play jars to get backward compatibility?

Neneath the output from `play classpath`:

```
hh@ubuntu10:/disk2/dba/lib$ /disk2/play-1.2.3/play classpath --%test-hh
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.2.3, http://www.playframework.org
~ framework ID is test-hh
~
~ Computed classpath is:
~ 
['/disk2/dba/lib/conf', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/play-1.2.3.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/modules/testrunner/lib/play-testrunner.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/activation-1.1.1.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/jj-simplecaptcha.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/javax.inject-1.0.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/commons-email-1.2.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/groovy-all-1.7.7.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/jj-wikitext.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/jj-textile.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/ehcache-core-2.0.0.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/ivy-2.2.0.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/signpost-core-1.2.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/jamon-2.7.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/postgresql-9.0.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/asm-all-3.3.1.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/jj-imaging.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/xstream-1.3.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/joda-time-1.6.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/snakeyaml-1.7.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/ezmorph-1.0.3.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/jta-1.1.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.6.0.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/jaxen-1.1.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/junit-4.8.1.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/oval-1.50.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/jregex-1.2_01.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/jsr107cache-1.0.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/commons-io-2.0.1.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/mail-1.4.3.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/commons-javaflow-1066591.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/memcached-2.6.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/h2-1.3.149.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/gson-1.7.1.jar', '/disk2/play-1.2.3/framework/lib/async-http-client-1.6.3.jar']
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems caused by two different play jar files under play-1.2.3/framework directory.

I compared the file "play/version" in play.jar and play-1.2.3.jar. For play.jar the version file content was "1.1.2" and for play-1.2.3.jar it was "1.2.3" as expected. My conclusion was that play.jar is an old version of the framework and included in the package by mistake, so I solved the case just by deleting play.jar from my play-1.2.3/framework directory.

For the specific incompatibility issue I suggest you just change your code. WsAsync.newRequest was changed already in Play 1.2.2 to

```
public WSRequest newRequest(String url, String encoding)
```